# I am not able to block Standby mode on a supervised device on iOS 17 programmatically

Tags: ios, mdm, restriction, ios17, lockdown

[image]

I am wondering if there is an easy way either through lockdownservice or through an MDM profile to block standby mode.

Something like `AllowStandbyMode: false`

I need this flag to programmatically disable this on a few hundred device in parallel.

I have been through the MDM docs, but not sure the frequency of uploads here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/restrictions?language=objc

Checked latest lockdownservice restrictions too but couldnt find anything like this:
https://github.com/hack-different/apple-knowledge/blob/2c8b5ea1247dd25a2c1f3d0baac5f9b61692f41a/_data/lockdownd.yaml#L540